# Skip rows based on date check from a STDOUT in shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am running a shell script under which i am running program which is writing output data on STDOUT and from there i am capturing the output and redirecting it into a file.
But that program writes a lot of data which i need to filter out when i am writing it into a file

```
test -d $data | grep "^[A-Z]*|[0-9]*" >> $OUT_FILE
```

Now in this output on row 3 i am getting a value on which i want to have a check if that values is less than 43564 then skip the row.

```
test -d $data | grep "^[A-Z]*|[0-9]*" | awk -F "|" 'if($3 >= 43564){print $0}'>> $OUT_FILE
```

But this is not working for me , suggest me what wrong i am doing

Comment: `test -d "$data"` doesn't write anything to standard output, and so there is nothing for `grep` to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, since there are no samples given so couldn't test it. As an important change you need to change from `=>` to `>=` in your `awk` condition. Then I have also fixed your `if` condition it ideally an `if` condition should be inside `{if(your condition)....}` braces.

Actually speaking we need not to have `if` condition we could simply run conditions itself and no need to mention `print` function too, because `awk` works on method of `regexp/condition` then `action` so if this condition is TRUE it will print that line(since no action mentioned and default action of `awk` is printing the current line).

As per @chepner comment comment `test -d` is NOT writing anything to standard output so changed it to a condition now.

```
if [[ test -d $data ]]
then
     awk -F "|" '/^[A-Z]*|[0-9]*/ && ($3 >= 43564)' Input_file > $OUT_FILE
else
     echo "Please check $data directory NOT present."
fi
```

***NOTE:*** We need to use `grep` with `awk`, since `awk` is capable of checking regex since this is OP's effort and I am going for OP's attempt fix here.

Comment: Thanks for the `=>` fix; shamelessly copied that into my answer. +1

Comment: I'm hoping so. I missed it myself but figured our answers were different enough that mine was worth keeping.

Comment: After looking at the answer i realized that my approach was not correct .

Answer (score 1):

You can't `grep` the output from `test` because it doesn't print anything.

Probably you want

```sh
test -d "$data" ||
awk -F "|" '/^[A-Z]*|[0-9]*/ && $3 >= 43564' "$data" >> "$OUT_FILE"
```

which is equivalent to the more beginner-friendly

```
if ! [ -d "$data" ]; then
   awk -F "|" '/^[A-Z]*|[0-9]*/ && $3 >= 43564' "$data" >> "$OUT_FILE"
fi
```

You almost never want to pipe `grep` to Awk; this is a very minor antipattern, but also very easy to avoid.  See [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)  Somewhat similarly, `{print $0}` is already the default action in Awk, so we can simply leave that out, and just specify conditions for when to print.

If you don't want to examine the file `$data` in the `then` part, obviously replace that part with the name of the file you want to filter. (Notice also [proper quoting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)) If you are filtering standard input, you can eminently well take out the file name and pipe to the entire `if` expression.

```sh
some complex process which generates this output |
if ! [ -d "$data" ]; then
    awk -F "|" '/^[A-Z]*|[0-9]*/ && $3 >= 43564'
fi >>"$OUT_FILE"
```